# Inheritance java

Tags: java, inheritance, netbeans, subclass, superclass

I am slightly confused with it and would like help.

I have created a superclass and a subclass but im trying to add a constructor method to the subclass that takes an integer and a String argument just like the one ive created in the superclass constructor then to use these 2 arguments to call the superclass constructor from within the subclass constructor so that the instance variables in the superclass are instantiated correctly

Ive created the subclass constructor but im stuck with the next part

Can anyone help me make sense of this?

Comment: The question you are asking is so intuitive. At least you should give it a thought before asking such questions. Also, if you are moving on to topics like inheritance, then you should have atleast this much knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
super(arg1, arg2)
```

as a first line in sub class constructor and check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html for more info

Comment: super will invoke the matching super class constructor

Answer (score 1):

```
class SuperClass
{
    protected SuperClass( int i, String s )
    {
        ...
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass
{
    public SubClass( int i, String s )
    {
        super( i, s );
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i would rate you up but i cant yet till i have more reputation

Comment: `inherits` is not a valid key word. It should be `extends`.

Comment: @ZouZou Yes i knew it was extends, but the structure is correct :)

Comment: Sorry about that, been in the C++/C# world recently. Was about to use `:`

Answer (score 1):

Being the following superclass

```
public class SuperClass{

    private Integer arg1;
    private String arg2;  

    public SuperClass(Integer arg1, String arg2){
        this.arg1 = arg1;
        this.arg2 = arg2;
    }
}
```

then, subclass and constructor should be

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass{

    // This should be the constructor
    public SubClass(Integer arg1, String arg2){
        super(arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```

As `super(arg1, arg2)` invokes the constructor on the SuperClass that receives an Integer and a String, and also is a valid constructor on SubClass.

Comment: Thanks alot, i would rate you up but i cant yet till i have more reputation :)

Comment: @Bob No issues , i ll rate it up